# I am experiencing an error with the timeslider in the leaftime package in R

Tags: r, leaflet

I am working with leaftime in R to try and create a map with a timeline that displays data using markers. I am experiencing what I think may be a bug in the package, where the date displayed on the time is not syncing correctly with the data, particularly, the date displayed is always one day behind what the data should be. This is also true for the example code in the package's help file.

I have tried adjusting the code by using the start and end commands in the sliderOptionsbut haven't been able to do so successfully. I have also adjusted the data itself to see if there was a problem with either the date or how it was inputted, but the error is consistent. Is this error a feature of the package or user error?

Code attached.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(leaflet)
library(leaftime)

ex_df <- data.frame(location = c('park', 'shopping center', 'school', 'library'),
                    latitude = c(50.432543,50.438524,50.445140,50.399818),
                    longitude = c(-78.534095, -78.567779,-78.523978,-78.507879),
                    count_1 = c(234, 3565, 4, 95),
                    count_2 = c(3, 6759, 280, 4820),
                    start = c('7/24/1999', '8/01/1999', '8/9/1999','8/19/1999'),
                    end = c('7/31/1999','8/8/1999','8/15/1999','8/26/1999'),
                    detected = c('detected', 'detected', 'not detected', 'detected'))

#change some of the values to dates and add the week of collection

ex_df<-ex_df %>% 
  mutate(start = mdy(start)) %>% 
  mutate(end = mdy(end)) %>% 
  mutate(week = epiweek(start))
#add the popup
ex_df<-ex_df %>% 
  mutate(popup_tab = paste0("<b>location:<b>",
                        location, "<br>",
                        "<b>week:<b>",
                        week,"<br>",
                        "<b>count_1:<b>",
                        count_1, "<br>",
                        "<b>count_2: <b>",
                        count_2, "<br>",
                        "<b>detected: <b>",
                        detected, "<br>"))

#change to a geojson object because thats what leaftime wants 
ex_geo <- geojsonio::geojson_json(ex_df, lat = "latitude", lon = "longitude")


#create the leaflet map . 
leaflet(ex_df) %>% 
  setView(lat = 50.42901, lng = -78.53343, zoom = 12) %>% 
  addTiles()%>%
  #creates the time slider
  addTimeline(data = ex_geo,
    sliderOpts = sliderOptions(
      formatOutput = htmlwidgets::JS(
         "function(date) {return new Date(date).toDateString()}"
      ),
    position = "topright",
    step = 10,
    duration = 30000,
    showTicks = TRUE),
    timelineOpts = timelineOptions( #L.marker is default
      pointToLayer = htmlwidgets::JS(
        "
        function(data, latlng){
        return L.marker(latlng, {}).bindPopup(data.properties.popup_tab) 
        }"
      ),
      styleOptions = NULL
    ))
```